# jQuery AJAX request returns JSON string and does not redirect on Windows Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jquery, azure

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC 3 website and everything works fine on the local version, but when I upload it on the cloud, the login process doesn't work as expected. Here's my login action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult Login(string username, string password)
    {
        password = Project_0._1._1.Cloud_Platform.Methods.Encrypt(password);

        REST_Auth.REST_AuthResponse loginResponse = REST_Auth.GetAuthToken(username, password, Project.Instance.AdModule.DeviceID);

        if (loginResponse.ErrorID != "AUTH00002")
        {
            HttpCookie _username = new HttpCookie("username");
            HttpCookie _password = new HttpCookie("password");
            HttpCookie _token = new HttpCookie("token");
            HttpCookie _userID = new HttpCookie("userID");
            _username.Value = username;
            _password.Value = password;
            _token.Value = loginResponse.Token;
            _userID.Value = loginResponse.UserID;

            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(_username);
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(_password);
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(_token);
            this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(_userID);
        }

        return Json(loginResponse);
    }
```

And here's the jQuery call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "login",
        data: $("#login_form").serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function () {
            $("#login_fields").fadeOut(300);
            if ($("#lresponse"))
                $("#lresponse").remove();
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            if (data.ErrorID == "AUTH00002") {
                $("#login_fields").fadeIn(500);
                $("#login_fields").append("<span id='lresponse'>Invalid login details. Try again</span>");
            }
            else {
                $("#login_fields").fadeIn(500);

                window.location = "/";
            }
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
```

On localhost it works as expected: On success, it redirects to the home page. Yet, on the cloud, live version, it just displays the JSON result, instead of rendering the HTML page. I have tried everything possible. Has anybody else dealt with this issue?

Comment: Is it hitting your error handler, and display the JSON result in an alert box? Or is it replacing the page content with the JSON result? In any case, it would be helpful if you traced the responses with Fiddler or a similar tool and compared the differences.

Comment: It hits the success function, and instead of redirecting, it replaces the page content with the JSON result. Did you encounter such a behaviour until now?

Comment: I can't think of anything specifically that would do that. You might find something by using Fiddler and compare the responses you get from localhost vs responses on the live site. My hunch is that it might involve the Content-Type of the response, but I could easily be wrong about that.

Comment: Why not let the server redirect on success and only return the json response in the error case?

Comment: @DPeden You happen to comment the exact same solution that I have found these days. I've changed the return type of the action from ActionResult to JsonResult and now it works as desired. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to post more code.

I believe that you're simply not cancelling the Form submission.  I see you have 'data:$("#login_form").serialize()' in your code, which when coupled with your description, leads to be believe this is the issue.

I don't think you're ever even calling your AJAX.

Comment: The AJAX is called. It's just that on the live server, it just returns the JSON string. However, I fixed it. The problem was that the action was declared as returning an ActionResult and I have changed it to a JsonResult. Now it works properly